# Complex LIKE Query extremely slow againt NVARCHAR(450), compared to VARCHAR(450)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm currently wondering about some performance differences on VARCHAR/NVARCHAR, especially when using Complex LIKE queries (that start with _ or %).

I have a testsetup on Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I have 2 Tables. Both have an ID Field (identity(1, 1), and a Value Field (either VARCHAR(450) OR NVARCHAR(450)). Both have the identical 1'000'000 randomly generated entries.

The tables are named tblVarCharNoIndex and tblNVarCharNoIndex (so, there are no indexes. The behaviour is nearly the same, if I use indexes).

Now, I execute the following queries test the duration (once on VARCHAR; once on NVARCHAR)

```
SELECT * FROM tblVarcharNoIndex WHERE Value LIKE '%ab%'
SELECT * FROM tblNVarcharNoIndex WHERE Value LIKE '%ab%'
```

The execution times are wildly different. It takes 1540ms on the VARCHAR Table, and 8630 ms on the NVARCHAR Table, so it takes over 5x longer with NVARCHAR.

I understand, that NVARCHAR has performance implications, since it needs 2 bytes to store, this totally makes sense. But I can't explain a performance degradation by 500%, this makes no sense to me.

As per Request, here some more Data.

**Query for table creation**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblVarcharNoIndex](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblVarcharNoIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblNVarcharNoIndex](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblNVarcharNoIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Query for value generation**

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @entries INT = 1000000 --1'000'000;
DECLARE @maxLength INT = 450;
DECLARE @minLength INT = 50;
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(450)
DECLARE @length INT

WHILE @cnt < @entries
BEGIN
    SELECT @value = ''
    SET @length = @minLength + CAST(RAND() * (@maxLength - @minLength) as INT)
    WHILE @length <> 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @value = @value + CHAR(CAST(RAND() * 96 + 32 as INT))
        SET @length = @length - 1
    END

    INSERT INTO tblBase(Value, NValue) VALUES (@value, @value)

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

END;
```

(Values are copied later from tblBase)

**LIKE Query in question**

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME
DECLARE @end DATETIME
DECLARE @testname NVARCHAR(100) = 'INSERT FROM other table'

--VARCHAR No Index
PRINT 'starting ''' + @testname + ''' on VARCHAR (No Index)'
SET @start = GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM tblVarcharNoIndex WHERE Value LIKE '%ab%' --This takes 1540ms

SET @end = GETDATE()
PRINT '-- finished ''' + @testname + ''' on VARCHAR (No Index)'
PRINT '-- Duration ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(mcs, @start, @end) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' microseconds'


--NVARCHAR No Index
PRINT 'starting ''' + @testname + ''' on NVARCHAR (No Index)'
SET @start = GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM tblNVarcharNoIndex WHERE Value LIKE '%ab%' --This takes 8630ms

SET @end = GETDATE()
PRINT '-- finished ''' + @testname + ''' on NVARCHAR (No Index)'
PRINT '-- Duration ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(mcs, @start, @end) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' microseconds'
```

**Execution Plan**
The execution plan for both the queries looks exactly the same (I have nowhere to upload the image right now, but it's really simple):

SELECT (0%) <--- Parallelism (Gather Streams) (3%) <--- Clustered Index Scan ON Primary Key (97%)

Comment: Check about `BIN` collate - http://aboutsqlserver.com/2015/01/20/optimizing-substring-search-performance-in-sql-server/

Comment: Have you compared execution plans?

Comment: Have you tried `Value LIKE N'%ab%'` on the nvarchar table? That might save a repetitive varchar>nvarchar conversion.

Comment: Just done a quick test of this on SQL 2012: varchar table takes an average of 5063ms to return ~150k rows from 1mil. nvarchar takes 6887ms compared to a **varchar** constant, and 6689 compared to an **nvarchar** constant (so probably not significant). So nvarchar is only about 35% slower on my setup.

Comment: `Complex LIKE queries (that start with _ or %)`. You'll never be able to use a normal index with this, so your query will **always** have to check every record in your table. If you really care about making this fast, look into **FULL TEXT INDEXES**.

Comment: Joel: I do understand, that the index cannot be used in this case. But i don't understand why the queries take 5 to 6 times longer to complete, when using NVARCHAR compared to VARCHAR. I would assume something in the area of 1.5 to 2 times slower

Comment: nvarchar is just twice slower (as expected) on my machine. Please show the output of the queries with "SET STATISTICS IO ON". Check if fragmentation is similar on both tables: SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('tblVarcharNoIndex'), NULL, NULL , 'SAMPLED')
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('tblNVarcharNoIndex'), NULL, NULL , 'SAMPLED')

Comment: @crazy_crank: How big is your table? Is there any chance that the changing from Varchar to Nvarchar increase the index level of your cluster index? If that is the case, then I guess the cost of the scan alone might be nearly doubled.

Comment: does this make a difference? SELECT * FROM tblNVarcharNoIndex WHERE Value LIKE N'%ab%'

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with how LIKE operates on unicode text.  ASCII LIKE is simple offset/between operation... e.g. LIKE %a is >= ASCII a character.  However in unicode the same "math" isn't true.  MS documentation even differentiates between "ASCII Pattern Matching" and  "Unicode Pattern Matching" I can't find docs on how these modes differ. See section "Pattern Matching using LIKE"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Interestingly the logical Reads are twice as many on the unicode table as ASCII.  I expected this.  Must be the extra CPU overhead for LIKE comparison.  CPU cycle count is 10x.  2106 vs  21247 as reported by Profiler.  Reads are 2x 28k vs 63k, and duration is 10x 1081 vs 10830.  To me this means it is all in the CPU usage for pattern matching and not an IO issue.

Comment: This is the closest I can come. SQL Server (2008) uses "...Unicode sorting rules. Because these rules are much more complex than non-Unicode sorting rules, they are more resource-intensive."    There are several other performance considerations in this article.   good luck.    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189617(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: please upload execution plan as xml for both queries

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie: Yes, I tried the like queries with LIKE N'%ab%', but it didn't make difference

Comment: @DVT: Index depth on the NVARCHAR table was 8, while beeing 6 on th VARCHAR table. But the problem persists, with and without an index, so this should not be the issue. The Table has 1'000'000 million rows, an integer PK and the (N)VARCHAR Field with string ranging from length 50 to 450

Comment: @ripvlan: I think your on the right track. I have not actually checked out the SQL Profiler stats, which I should have, but the increase in CPU cycles is probably the reason for the massive increase... (Interestingly though, sorting was no especially slow, only arround 20% slower than on a VARCHAR table)
I do not assume, that you have an idea to mitigate this effect? Could maybe a different collation could have an effect? I'm thinking, this is just an issue, we have to live with?

Comment: @crazy_crank: This is my guess of what happened. Your table is huge (10^12 rows as you stated 1000000 million rows). Since you clustered index depth is two levels higher, (6 to 8) meaning that it takes a lot longer to load and scan through the whole table (2 to 4 times). Also, because NVARCHAR is twice the size of VARCHAR, it would also take longer to compare and match each string (1.1 to 2). Multiply these two factors together, 5 times longer is not an outrageous number.

Comment: @crazy_crank I don't know of a way to overcome this.  But I would go back to basics - what is your requirement? LIKE %abc% will always be a table scan.  Unicode looking for ASCII - are you sure this is the correct implementation?  Don't think Collation matters with Unicode in this case - both input and storage are same.  Can you extract data into another "thingy" and do search with different technology?

Comment: @crazy_crank I've seen other people post on SO with similar "why doesn't my [table-scan-query] not work well?" and I've always countered with -- is this really a query your app is going to execute?  Are you optimizing for a non-realistic query?  Docs talk about how Unicode rules are more expensive.  Index depth seems fine, structure seems fine.  My guess is the Unicode "tax" and there may be more to your unicode implementation.    Such as Full-text search.

Comment: I second the opinion of @ripvlan above.

Comment: @DVT ups, it's a million rows, not a million million, my bad. But your conclusions stay correct nevertheless

Comment: @ripvlan It was more of a basic question to better understand the performance implications of unicode (We're making a big migration of VARCHAR to NVARCHAR, since we need unicode capabillities in our application). I exptected a degration, but not as extreme as it was and was lacking the knowledge to find out why. So your comments were really helpfull, thanks. I'll keep your propositions in the back of my head, for the case, that performance becomes a real problem.

Comment: @Kyll fixed that, sorry :)

Comment: You are returning rows to the client, so I would expect that not only is the query slower but also you are returning twice as much data to the client. Have you tried the timings when you do an SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM tblVarCharNoIndex etc.

Comment: Further to my comment above When I do this I get near identical times (differing in less than 1/2 second) despite the second query reading twice as many pages.

Comment: Understanding new stuff is great a track.  One thing I noticed while (re)reading the Unicode docs is that part about Server/Client differences - and making sure both ends are the same.  This has never been a problem for me because we deploy both ends.  But it requires documentation to be explicit.  You might try that out to understand how it might make a difference.   We don't Search nvarchar - for us it is display only for User language/locale information.

Comment: Show a complete executable script that reproduces the issue your end. This script is not complete (missing definition of `tblBase` and any code to populate `tblVarcharNoIndex` etc) and is missing details such as column collation.

Comment: Can you please check runtimes for `SELECT COUNT (*)`?

Comment: Could you please execute the queries with SET STATISTICS TIME ON and share the results? CPU and Elapsed time for both queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory though is sound. `LIKE` is an operator that compares each value against a portion of a string. If the operator is truly based properly and if `SQL Server` was not aware of the advantages of one part of the value over the other, then `SQL Server` would necessarily have to run an algorithm like the following (example in `C#`):

```
        for (; foundValue == false && Start < (length - 2); Start += 1)
        {
            searchValue = x.Substring(Start, 2);
            if (searchValue == compareValue)
                foundValue = true;
        }
```

only there is twice as many characters in `NVARCHAR`.

From my own testing, I note the following:

> Table 'tblVarcharNoIndex'. Scan count 1, logical reads 97, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'tblNVarcharNoIndex'. Scan count 1, logical reads 189, physical
>   reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads
>   0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Logical Reads implies how much SQL was storing for the comparisons, and we notice this is a little over 2x. I think the answer can be seen when looking at the Actual Execution Plan and noting the estimated number of rows was 56 vs 73, even thought the same number of rows was ultimately returned.

A look at the Client Statistics, however, shows what you probably noticed:

```
                                                        NVAR    VAR     AVERAGE
Query Profile Statistics                    
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements        0       0       0.0000
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       0       0.0000
  Number of SELECT statements                           2       2       2.0000
  Rows returned by SELECT statements                    306     306     306.0000
  Number of transactions                                0       0       0.0000
Network Statistics                  
  Number of server roundtrips                           1       1       1.0000
  TDS packets sent from client                          1       1       1.0000
  TDS packets received from server                      45      23      34.0000
  Bytes sent from client                                146     144     145.0000
  Bytes received from server                            180799  91692   136245.5000
Time Statistics                 
  Client processing time                                286     94      190.0000
  Total execution time                                  317     156     236.5000
  Wait time on server replies                           31      62      46.5000
```

Notice the TDS packets received from the server was different (recall the estimation of rows was disparate), which not only takes up more bytes but time to process. Execution time about 2x, yet the processing time was 3x the amount.

How much of this is related to your processor vs SQL Server's protocols? Probably some or a lot of it (this query was run on an ancient EDU Lenovo laptop w/Windows 10, DuoCore 1.64Ghz, 16GB DDR3). Though the specifics I am unqualified to answer.

Still, we can conclude one thing: **SQL Server's estimation of rows has an impact on the client and data sent/received**.

Answer (score 4):

It will not be possible to give you specifics without more data, starting with an execution plan for both queries.

Some general reasons:

> 1. As you stated there are twice as many bytes to read when doing a scan
> 2. The number of page loads will increase
> 3. The amount of necessary memory will increase, which can cause overflow to disk operations
> 4. The amount of CPU will can increase which might be capped based on OS or SQL settings and be causing CPU waits.

Comment: Thanks for the initial help. 
I think, 3. isn't the case, since execution mode (according to the execution plan) is Row and Storage is RowStore. 
I also don't think 4, since I have no limitiations set on the database. 
1. should not increase the required time by 5 times. 
I think 2 could be the issue. Is it possible, this has such a massive impact? 

I als have added some scripts and described the query plan. tell me, if you need more info.

Comment: All of his statements are definitely true to some degree.  The issue is finding out which one is the actual performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

**Unicode comparison rules are much more complicated than ascii rules.**

> The effect of Unicode data on performance is complicated by a variety of factors that include the following:
>
> - The difference between Unicode sorting rules and non-Unicode sorting rules
> - The difference between sorting double-byte and single-byte characters
> - Code page conversion between client and server

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189617.aspx

You can confirm this by changing the collation of the column to binary.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #temp2
where col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin2 like '%str%'
```

Lastly, some considerations if you have to use NVARCHAR and want to improve performance.

- Consider data compression. When you page/row compress in SQL Server, your nvarchar cols are automatically UNICODE compressed too. () https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835(v=sql.105).aspx
- Consider changing collation. This has implications for sorting/searching. So test if it gives desired results across languages/characters.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in some of the other posts the biggest impact on your performance in this scenario is the Unicode comparison rules.  You can work around the problem with regards to ‘LIKE’ comparison queries by adding a non-persisted calculated field with a binary collation to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE tblNVarcharNoIndex
ADD ValueColBin AS UPPER(Value) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_Bin2;
```

Instead of querying your persisted data field you can now query the calculated field instead.  Note that binary collation is case sensitive so in order to perform case insensitive searches you will have to convert your search strings to upper case. The following example shows what the updated query will look like:

```
DECLARE @compare  NVARCHAR(10) = N'%AB%'

SELECT   [Id]
        ,[Value] 
FROM    tblNVarcharNoIndex 
WHERE   [ValueColBin]  LIKE @compare collate Latin1_General_100_Bin2
```

There will still be a performance hit however it should be within the expected range of 1.5 to 2 slower (in theory at least). Note that this method will incur a higher CPU cost.

Answer (score 0):

Query that uses a varchar parameter does an index seek due to column collation sets.

query that uses a nvarchar parameter does an index scan due to column collation sets.

The basic rule to follow is Scans are bad, Seeks are good.

**Index Scan**

When SQL Server does a scan it loads the object which it wants to read from disk into memory, then reads through that object from top to bottom looking for the records that it needs.

**Index Seek**

When SQL Server does a seek it knows where in the index that the data is going to be, so it loads up the index from disk, goes directly to the part of the index that it needs and reads to where the data that it needs ends. This is obviously a much more efficient operation than a scan, as SQL already knows where the data it is looking for is located.

How can I modify an Execution Plan to use a Seek instead of a Scan?

When SQL Server is looking for your data probably one of the largest things which will make SQL Server switch from a seek to a scan is when some of the columns are you looking for are not included in the index you want it to use. Most often this will have SQL Server fall back to doing a clustered index scan, since the Clustered index contains all the columns in the table. This is one of the biggest reasons (in my opinion at least) that we now have the ability to INCLUDE columns in an index, without adding those columns to the indexed columns of the index. By including the additional columns in the index we increase the size of the index, but we allow SQL Server to read the index, without having togo back to the clustered index, or to the table it self to get these values.

**References**

For information regarding the specifics of each of these operators within a SQL Server Execution plan see....

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175184.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190400.aspx